# How can I change my busy disk?

Tags: disk

I need to change my disk type, but my **disk** is busy and I am using Ubuntu 23.04.

Note: I am new to **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here, but a busy disk is an indication that it is in use.  If the disk is the one you booted from then it will always be busy.  To get around this you would need to boot to a Live environment like a USB or DVD to change a disk type.

Comment: What do you mean by "disk type"?  Your disk is always going to be busy if you're booted into the computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.